# Records are displaying twice when there are more than one records

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I am displaying the data from the database.

I am displaying data on view (Expected output)

### **Row 1**

```
AFGFD ANAND
trdsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | Activity_startTime | Activity_endTime
cricket        | 05:00.             | 08:00
```

---

**Row 2**

```
POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | Activity_startTime | Activity_endTime
cricket        | 05:00.             | 08:00
Badminton      | 09:00.             | 11:00
```

The issue is, the first row is displayed perfectly because I have only one activity but in the second row I am getting more than one records.

I am getting the output for the second row like

```
POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

POIUY ANAND
mnbsd@gmail.com

ActivityName   | Activity_startTime | Activity_endTime
cricket        | 05:00.             | 08:00
ActivityName   | Activity_startTime | Activity_endTime
Badminton      | 09:00.             | 11:00
```

How do I display the personal info and activity info separately?

I know I used 2 `foreach` that's the reason I am getting my output. I think I have change model query to display the personal info and activity info.

**view code**

```
foreach ($SActivity as $sec_data) {
    foreach ($sec_data as $row) { ?>
        <h2><?php echo $row->first_name;?><?php echo $row->last_name;?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $row->email;?></p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ActivityName</th>
                    <th>Activity_startTime</th>
                    <th>Activity_endTime</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->ActivityName;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Activity_startTime;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Activity_endTime;?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php }
}
```

I am getting the output in the view page

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [member_id] => 209
                    [customer_id] => 20183
                    [profile_pic] => 5bb76975b6c4a1538746741051018.JPG
                    [first_name] => AFGFD
                    [middle_name] => 
                    [last_name] => ANAND
                    [email] => trdsd@gmail.com
                    [dob] => 24-07-1982
                    [phone] => 0987654321
                    [activity_name_id]=>1
                    [activity_name]=>cricket
                    [activity_startTime]=>05:00
                    [activity_endTime]=>08:00
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [member_id] => 337
                    [customer_id] => 20184
                    [profile_pic] => 5bc7363f4fadf1539782207171018.jpg
                    [first_name] => POIUY
                    [middle_name] => 
                    [last_name] => ANAND
                    [email] => mnbsd@gmail.com
                    [dob] => 17-04-2006
                    [phone] => 0987654314
                    [activity_name_id]=>1
                    [activity_name]=>cricket
                    [activity_startTime]=>05:00
                    [activity_endTime]=>08:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [member_id] => 337
                    [customer_id] => 20184
                    [profile_pic] => 5bc7363f4fadf1539782207171018.jpg
                    [first_name] => POIUY
                    [middle_name] => 
                    [last_name] => ANAND
                    [email] => mnbsd@gmail.com
                    [dob] => 17-04-2006
                    [phone] => 0987654314
                    [activity_name_id]=>2
                    [activity_name]=>Badminton
                    [activity_startTime]=>09:00
                    [activity_endTime]=>11:00
                )

        )

)
```

**controller**

```
//getting personal information
$getLoginMemberDetails['getAlldata'] = $this->Member_model->getAlldata();

$allData = [];
foreach ($getLoginMemberDetails['getAlldata'] as $m_id) {
    $allData[] = $this->Member_model->getMemberActivity($m_id->member_id);
}

$getLoginMemberDetails['SActivity'] = $allData;
```

**Model**

```
public function getSecondaryMemberActivity($gotMemberId)
{
    $getDetails = ['members.member_id' => $gotMemberId];
    $result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
        ->from('members')
        ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id','LEFT')
        ->join('activity_name', 'activity_name.activity_name_id = member_activity.activity_id','LEFT')
        ->get()
        ->result();

    if($result) {
        return $result;  
    } else  {
        return 0;    
    }
}
```

Would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: How does this question about CodeIgniter PHP and displaying database records have anything to do with jQuery or jQuery Validate.  Please only use tags that are most relevant to the content of the question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky, Noted. I will not repeat this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your view. I have only added a counter to keep track of the number of activities for each user, and keep track of the current position in the loop in order to print out only one table header and user info for each user:

```
<?php 
foreach ($SActivity as $sec_data) {

    $counter = 0; // COUNTER FOR KNOWING POSITION IN ACTIVITIES LOOP 
    $num_activities = count($sec_data); // TOTAL NUMBER OF ACTIVITIES FOR THIS USER

    foreach ($sec_data as $row) { 
        $counter++; // ADD +1 TO COUNTER FOR EACH ACTIVITY

        // ONLY PRINT OUT THE NAME AND TABLE HEADER IF FIRST ROW 
        if($counter == 1){ ?>

        <h2><?php echo $row->first_name;?><?php echo $row->last_name;?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $row->email;?></p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ActivityName</th>
                    <th>Activity_startTime</th>
                    <th>Activity_endTime</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

        <?php } ?>      

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->ActivityName;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Activity_startTime;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Activity_endTime;?></td>
                </tr>

        <?php 
        // IF THIS IS THE LAST ACTIVITY OF THIS USER IN THE LOOP: PRINT TABLE END TAG
        if($counter == $num_activities){
            echo '</tbody></table>';
        }
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks for the help @MichaelK

Comment: Hello @michaelK, if posible then can you help me out with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280987/after-adding-the-product-in-the-cart-and-the-user-refreshes-the-page-then-how-ca